# Can lists be to big in R? R won't let me create this list

Tags: r

This is a list with the years 1987-2021 with 12 months per year. R won't let me create this
list unless I remove some entries or divide it into two smaller pieces. If I run the code as-is, the console will show a plus sign in the console and no object will be created. If I remove some data from the list, it will work.

Any clues on what's happening??

```
pxweb_query_list <- 
  list("ContentsCode"=c("000001R4"),
       "Tid"=c("1987M01","1987M02","1987M03","1987M04","1987M05","1987M06","1987M07","1987M08","1987M09","1987M10","1987M11","1987M12","1988M01","1988M02","1988M03","1988M04","1988M05","1988M06","1988M07","1988M08","1988M09","1988M10","1988M11","1988M12","1989M01","1989M02","1989M03","1989M04","1989M05","1989M06","1989M07","1989M08","1989M09","1989M10","1989M11","1989M12","1990M01","1990M02","1990M03","1990M04","1990M05","1990M06","1990M07","1990M08","1990M09","1990M10","1990M11","1990M12","1991M01","1991M02","1991M03","1991M04","1991M05","1991M06","1991M07","1991M08","1991M09","1991M10","1991M11","1991M12","1992M01","1992M02","1992M03","1992M04","1992M05","1992M06","1992M07","1992M08","1992M09","1992M10","1992M11","1992M12","1993M01","1993M02","1993M03","1993M04","1993M05","1993M06","1993M07","1993M08","1993M09","1993M10","1993M11","1993M12","1994M01","1994M02","1994M03","1994M04","1994M05","1994M06","1994M07","1994M08","1994M09","1994M10","1994M11","1994M12","1995M01","1995M02","1995M03","1995M04","1995M05","1995M06","1995M07","1995M08","1995M09","1995M10","1995M11","1995M12","1996M01","1996M02","1996M03","1996M04","1996M05","1996M06","1996M07","1996M08","1996M09","1996M10","1996M11","1996M12","1997M01","1997M02","1997M03","1997M04","1997M05","1997M06","1997M07","1997M08","1997M09","1997M10","1997M11","1997M12","1998M01","1998M02","1998M03","1998M04","1998M05","1998M06","1998M07","1998M08","1998M09","1998M10","1998M11","1998M12","1999M01","1999M02","1999M03","1999M04","1999M05","1999M06","1999M07","1999M08","1999M09","1999M10","1999M11","1999M12","2000M01","2000M02","2000M03","2000M04","2000M05","2000M06","2000M07","2000M08","2000M09","2000M10","2000M11","2000M12","2001M01","2001M02","2001M03","2001M04","2001M05","2001M06","2001M07","2001M08","2001M09","2001M10","2001M11","2001M12","2002M01","2002M02","2002M03","2002M04","2002M05","2002M06","2002M07","2002M08","2002M09","2002M10","2002M11","2002M12","2003M01","2003M02","2003M03","2003M04","2003M05","2003M06","2003M07","2003M08","2003M09","2003M10","2003M11","2003M12","2004M01","2004M02","2004M03","2004M04","2004M05","2004M06","2004M07","2004M08","2004M09","2004M10","2004M11","2004M12","2005M01","2005M02","2005M03","2005M04","2005M05","2005M06","2005M07","2005M08","2005M09","2005M10","2005M11","2005M12","2006M01","2006M02","2006M03","2006M04","2006M05","2006M06","2006M07","2006M08","2006M09","2006M10","2006M11","2006M12","2007M01","2007M02","2007M03","2007M04","2007M05","2007M06","2007M07","2007M08","2007M09","2007M10","2007M11","2007M12","2008M01","2008M02","2008M03","2008M04","2008M05","2008M06","2008M07","2008M08","2008M09","2008M10","2008M11","2008M12","2009M01","2009M02","2009M03","2009M04","2009M05","2009M06","2009M07","2009M08","2009M09","2009M10","2009M11","2009M12","2010M01","2010M02","2010M03","2010M04","2010M05","2010M06","2010M07","2010M08","2010M09","2010M10","2010M11","2010M12","2011M01","2011M02","2011M03","2011M04","2011M05","2011M06","2011M07","2011M08","2011M09","2011M10","2011M11","2011M12","2012M01","2012M02","2012M03","2012M04","2012M05","2012M06","2012M07","2012M08","2012M09","2012M10","2012M11","2012M12","2013M01","2013M02","2013M03","2013M04","2013M05","2013M06","2013M07","2013M08","2013M09","2013M10","2013M11","2013M12","2014M01","2014M02","2014M03","2014M04","2014M05","2014M06","2014M07","2014M08","2014M09","2014M10","2014M11","2014M12","2015M01","2015M02","2015M03","2015M04","2015M05","2015M06","2015M07","2015M08","2015M09","2015M10","2015M11","2015M12","2016M01","2016M02","2016M03","2016M04","2016M05","2016M06","2016M07","2016M08","2016M09","2016M10","2016M11","2016M12","2017M01","2017M02","2017M03","2017M04","2017M05","2017M06","2017M07","2017M08","2017M09","2017M10","2017M11","2017M12","2018M01","2018M02","2018M03","2018M04","2018M05","2018M06","2018M07","2018M08","2018M09","2018M10","2018M11","2018M12","2019M01","2019M02","2019M03","2019M04","2019M05","2019M06","2019M07","2019M08","2019M09","2019M10","2019M11","2019M12","2020M01","2020M02","2020M03","2020M04","2020M05","2020M06","2020M07","2020M08","2020M09","2020M10","2020M11","2020M12","2021M01","2021M02","2021M03","2021M04","2021M05","2021M06"))
```

The **solution** was given by @Limey. Just add some linebreaks manually, and it will work.

Comment: That is strange.  I couldn't reproduce your problem.  `str(pxweb_query_list)#
List of 2
 $ ContentsCode: chr "000001R4"
 $ Tid         : chr [1:414] "1987M01" "1987M02" "1987M03" "1987M04" ...`

Comment: Did you try to print the list?

Comment: There’s a limit on the length of a line of input in RStudio. I can’t remember what it is. Put some line breaks in your definition of the Tid column. Yes. It’s [4095 bytes](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc).